# Send and receive texts through a desktop computer

Tags: macos, sms, blackberry

Is there any BlackBerry Software through which I can send and receive my texts through a mac desktop?

Answer (score 2):

I have used [Blurts](http://www.mlhsoftware.com/Blurts/index.html) with a lot of success on windows.

There is the Cortado line of software. The [free](http://software.crackberry.com/product.asp?id=25721&n=Cortado-SMS2Desk) version is here. There is a premium version as well. It works by email. So you basically get an email of the txt and you reply to it, once your phone gets it. It will then send the txt out.

Comment: Thanks but is there any for mac os x?

Thanks.

Comment: Ill see what I can find. I edited your questions to show you wanted to do it via a mac.

Answer (score 0):

I know you can send SMS from your provider's website. You can't receive it since SMS is a protocol that works with NPA/NXX on a mobile device or PSTN.

You can't receive it on your computer if the sms is sent to your blackberry. I have a Storm and the keyboard is horrible so I wanted to have the same thing you're talking about but ***it's not possible unfortunately***!